# How can we find the limits of this integration $\iiint_{G}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ with cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

Let $$G=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\ x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2,\ (x^2+y^2)^2\geq a^2(x^2-y^2),\ z\geq 0\right\}$$

If we apply cylindral coordinates on $G$ we have that $0\leq z \leq \sqrt{4a^{2}-r^{2}}$ but if $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ we have that $a\sqrt{\cos{2\theta}}\leq r \leq 2a$ and if $-\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta \leq 0$ we have that $0\leq r \leq 2a$.

How can find the limis of integration  $\iiint\limits_{G}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ with the use of cylindral coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mbox{Lets}\ \vec{r} \equiv x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + z\,\hat{z}}\,\,\,
\mbox{and}
\\ &
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{G\! \equiv\!
\braces{\!\vec{r} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}:\! r^{2}\! \leq a^{2},
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}^{2}\! \geq\! a^{2}\pars{x^{2} - y^{2}},
z \geq 0\!}}
\end{align}

---

Hereafter, I'll be using *Cylindrical Coordinates*. Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} +z^{2} \leq a^{2}}
\bracks{\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}^{2} \geq a^{2}\pars{x^{2} - y^{2}}}}
\\ &\ \bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\phantom{\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\,}\bracks{z \geq 0}\dd^{3}\vec{r}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{r^{2} + z^{2} \leq a^{2}}
\bracks{r^{4} \geq a^{2}r^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}
\\ &\ \phantom{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\,\,}
r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{r^{2}\ \mapsto\ r}{=} &\
{1 \over 2}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{a^{2}\cos\pars{\phi} \leq r \leq a^{2} - z^{2}}
\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\verts{a}^{3}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\cos\pars{\phi} \leq r \leq 1 - z^{2}}
\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\end{align}

---

Note that $\ds{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\on{f}\pars{\cos\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{%
\on{f}\pars{\sin\pars{\phi}} +
\on{f}\pars{-\sin\pars{\phi}}}\dd\phi}$.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} +z^{2} \leq a^{2}}
\bracks{\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}^{2} \geq a^{2}\pars{x^{2} - y^{2}}}}
\\ &\ \bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\phantom{\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\,}\bracks{z \geq 0}\dd^{3}\vec{r}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\sin\pars{\phi} \leq r \leq
1 - z^{2}}\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[2mm] + &
\verts{a}^{3}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{-\sin\pars{\phi} \leq r \leq
1 - z^{2}}\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\bracks{\sin\pars{\phi} \leq 1 - z^{2}}\bracks{%
1 - z^{2} - \sin\pars{\phi}}\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[2mm] + &
\verts{a}^{3}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\pars{1 - z^{2}}\dd\phi\,\dd z}
_{\ds{\pi \over 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\root{1 - \sin\pars{\phi}}}
\bracks{1 - z^{2} - \sin\pars{\phi}}\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[2mm] + &
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\verts{a}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\bracks{1 - \sin\pars{\phi}}^{3/2}\,\dd\phi +
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\verts{a}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{1 - \sin^{2}\pars{\phi} \over
\bracks{1 + \sin\pars{\phi}}^{3/2}}\,\cos\pars{\phi}\,\dd\phi +
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\verts{a}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\verts{a}^{3}\int_{0}^{1}
{1 - t^{2} \over
\pars{1 + t}^{3/2}}\dd t +
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\verts{a}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over 3}\verts{a}^{3}\int_{1}^{2}
\pars{2t^{-1/2} - t^{1/2}}\dd t +
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\verts{a}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{3\pi + 16\root{2} - 20 \over 9}\,\verts{a}^{3}}
\approx 1.3391\,\verts{a}^{3} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The first condition gives you points inside a sphere of radius a. Take square root of second condition , you see that gives you the points outside a cylinder, radius a^{1/4}.